# Unexpected argument in python

Tags: python, oop, pycharm, coder

```
class Employee:
    def __int__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary

    def getsalary(self):
        print( self.salary)

rohan = Employee("Rohan","345500")
print(rohan.salary)
print(rohan.name)
#rohan.getsalary()

harry = Employee("Harry", "521000")
print(harry.salary)
print(harry.name)
```

Could found what is the problem just said that unexpected argument. can any one solve this or help me

output:-
The result should be 345500
rohan
521000
harry

Comment: You have spelled `__init__` incorrectly, you're missing an "i"

Comment: @Iain Shelvington ohho ,thanks buddy.

Answer (score 1):

It is spelling mistake in the `__init__` method. When you pass arguments while instantiating an object, it will look for a **init** method to pass the arguments.

```py
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary

    def getsalary(self):
        print( self.salary)

rohan = Employee("Rohan","345500")
print(rohan.salary)
print(rohan.name)
#rohan.getsalary()

harry = Employee("Harry", "521000")
print(harry.salary)
print(harry.name)
```